# How to add persistent connection support to a load-balanced HTTP webservice

Tags: web-services, keep-alive, haproxy, persistent-connection

We are working on an HTTP webservice load-balanced using haproxy. The webservice is accessed via SSL. It is a RESTful HTTP service and simply accepts JSON, does some work, and returns JSON. There is no notion of a session.

We have redundant load-balancers set up in front of a pair of redundant webservice servers. Each server sits behind Apache, where Apache is used as a proxy in order to handle SSL and logging. If it matters, our webservice is a Clojure (java) application using compojure (jetty) to handle HTTP.

This is a brief diagram showing the path of a client request through our existing system.

`client request -> haproxy (load balancing) -> apache (ssl, logging) -> webservice`

We would like any connection to the load-balancer to establish a persistent connection and then be served by the same server for all subsequent requests sent through that persistent connection. In other words, we don't want a persistent connection to haproxy making requests to more than one webservice server.

How would you recommend that we get this working? How can we "pin" a given connection to the load-balancer to a specific webservice server? How could we prevent accidentally loading down a specific webservice server with multiple intensive requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `balance source` in the `defaults` block, along with removing `option httpclose` entries did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In our HAProxy configuration we do this at the backend level, using the `cookie` option. This is because he have a number of sites, some of which we do want persistance for - others we do not.

In those that we do the backend looks like this in `haproxy.cfg`:

```
backend examplesite
cookie STK insert indirect nocache maxidle 30m maxlife 8h
server server1 192.168.0.1:80 cookie n1
server server2 192.168.0.2:80 cookie n2
```

This will set a cookie with the name `STK` on the first request. Haproxy will automatically assign a value to this cookie that it will then use to send subsequent requests to the same node.

We decided to also add the `n1` and `n2` cookie prefixes... this means that the cookie value will be prefixed with either `n1` if the requests are going to node 1 or `n2` if they are going to node 2. This is very helpful when debugging.

---

Either way I'd suggest taking a look at the [configuration documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt) around `cookie` options.

You might also want to look at the `appsession` option. This allows HAProxy to use an existing cookie (such as ASPNetSessionId or PHPSESSIONID) for the same purpose.

I had problems with it before, but recently had an answer to a question of Server Fault which should resolve this. You could give it a go as it saves using an extra cookie in your requests. [Can't get appsession setting in HAProxy to work](https://serverfault.com/questions/254001/cant-get-appsession-setting-in-haproxy-to-work).

Comment: Thanks. We are running an HTTP webservice that accepts and returns JSON. Clients connecting to the webservice are not browsers so I've a doubt that cookies could be useful in this instance.